# Connecting and filtering Comboboxes in VB thru Microsoft SQL

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am very new to programming and need some guidance.

I have a MS SQL Database of items (product_cat, product_type, product_make, product_Model).  I have a win form with 4 comboboxes related to these column.  What I want is to be able to select product_cat and it filters product_type based on that.  For example:  if i select category "Transportation" it filters everything related to transportation into combobox2 (product_type) cars, buses, train... then when i select cars it filters and fills combobox3 (product_make).  Right now my code is showing everything in all the comboboxes and wont filter anything.  Thank you for any guidance.

```
Public Class Form1 
   Public sql As New sqlcontrol 
   Private DBcmd As SqlCommand 
   Public Sub loadcbxCategory()
      cbxCategory.Items.Clear()
      sql.ExeQuery("Select DISTINCT Product_Category From dbo.Product_Data$;") 
      If sql.HasExecption(True) Then Exit Sub 
      For Each r As DataRow In sql.DBDT.Rows
         cbxCategory.Items.Add(r("Product_Category").ToString)
      Next
   End Sub

   Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load 
      loadcbxCategory() 
   ...

   Private Sub cbxCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbxCategory.SelectedIndexChanged 
      Dim mysqlconn = New SqlConnection mysqlconn.ConnectionString = ("Server=mojiz-surface\sqlexpress;database=ASI_Inventory;trusted_connection=true;")
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve].

Comment: This is the link to the whole code so far: https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApNd8R9fwYWegd02XZnQILU2b3fkKg https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApNd8R9fwYWegd03ze8tDYnu4uROAQ

Comment: Try to add If Not Page.IsPostBack Then loadcbxCategory().
Loading probably causes selected index change and overwrite anything selected.

Answer (score 1):

**Try This You have to enter just combo box name and pass the query parameters**

```
Class SurroundingClass
Private path = "Your connection string"
Private con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(path)

Public Sub ComboData(ByVal cmb As ComboBox, ByVal colname As String, ByVal dbname As String, ByVal wherecondition As String)
    con.open()
    cmb.Items.Clear()
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("select " & colname & " from " & dbname & " where " & wherecondition, con)
    dt = New DataTable()
    da.Fill(dt)

    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        cmb.Items.Add(row(0).ToString())
    Next

    con.close()
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim sample as new sqlcommand ("select*From *your datable in sqldatabase*", connection)
Dim adapter as new sqldataAdapter(sample)
Dim table as new DataTable()

adapter.fill(table)
combobox1.DataSource = Table
Combobox1.Valuemember = "No." (NOTE: *Select the column from your sql data table*)
```

hope it will help you..